# Guest os on VMware workstation v7 cannot ping host OS when bridged on wireless adapter

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I recently got a new Windows 7 (64 bit) laptop at work and I installed the trial version of VMware Workstation 7.1 and setup two guest OS'es - Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 Professional both of which are 64 bit.

The guest VMs CANNOT ping the host OS *when Vmnet0 bridging is set to automatic or exclusively bound to the wireless adapter* (under virtual network editor). However the Host system can ping and access guest VM admin shares under this setup.

Now *when vmnet0 is bridged to the ethernet adapter exclusively*, the guest VMs are able to connect to host OS.

Until recently i have been using VMware server 2.0 installed on Windows XP (host OS) laptop with two guest OS, Win XP and Win 2003 (32 bit) and vmnet0 bridging was set to "bridged to an automatically chosen adapter". I never had any issues with the VMs connecting with host when i was connected to the network via ethernet or wireless adapter.

According to VMware, wireless adapter bridging is supported from v4.0. Is there any thing that needs to be configured on the wireless adapter in Windows 7 or in Vmware workstation to make bridging work successfully from guest to host as well? 
Wireless adapter model is - intel centrino ultimate N6300.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't have an answer yet, I'll try suggesting something a little off the wall...

Does your wireless access point have station isolation turned on? This feature of APs restricts wifi clients from talking to each other. They can only talk to the AP and then on to the wired connection of the AP. I've seen more and more corporate environments turning this on.